# sp_send_dbmail invalid argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, parameters

I am sending a mail using the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure(From system databases).

I am doing it as,

[image]

My question is what value should I put for the parameter

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectsParameter
```

Is there a way to pass on a blank / Null value for this parameter ?

Comment: Show your as a text, not as an image..

Comment: @SonerGönül I just need to know what I can pass as empty parameters for the System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectsParameter.